# XCTest: Taping in the navigationItem back button

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode9, xctest

I'm trying to figure out how to in the navigationItem back button using XCTest:

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.target
```

and

```
po vc.detailVC.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem
```

and both cases comes as nil object. I check the navegationItem:

```
po vc.navigationItem
<<UINavigationItem: 0x7fa6f2d02b60>: title:'(null)'>
```

Any of you knows how can tap in the navigation back button using XCTest ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

Normally you can tap the Back button using the following XCTest code

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launch()
// ...
app.navigationBars.buttons.element(boundBy: 0).tap()
```

Comment: I'm getting this error Value of type 'vc' has no member 'navigationBars'

Comment: As I mention on my question I'm trying to tap in the back button of the navigation using XCTest. When I add you code you mention above I get the following error: *** Assertion failure in -[XCUIApplication init]

Comment: @user2924482 Check you are reusing the XCUIApplication instance, not creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your test function

```
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.navigationBars["Master"].buttons["Back"].tap()
```

Comment: On this line `let app = XCUIApplication()` I getting this error: `*** Assertion failure in -[XCUIApplication init]`

Answer (score 0):

As for the path: Record a new test, tap on the element and check the path, it gives you and rewrite it to your own test.

As for the `*** Assertion failure in -[XCUIApplication init]` - Do you have your `setUp` and `tearDown` blocks set properly?

For both, check: https://code.kiwi.com/guide-to-advanced-ui-tests-on-ios-8950355d2649